# Why don't the letters 'ST' don't show on my browser using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am making a website and I am getting data from my database(local database for testing of course) and for some reason, the two letter `st` won't show up on my browser. I am using PHP and MySQL with phpMyAdmin.

I have tried this with several words like: "Test" just shows "Te", "String" just shows "ring" and even with st in the middle of a word like "Abstract" just shows "Abract". I have tried searching for answers but i couldn't find anything at all!

```
$DBConnect = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
if ($DBConnect === FALSE) {
    echo "<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>" . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno() . ": " . mysqli_error() . "</p>";
} else {
    $DBName = "cms";
    $TableName = "messages";
    if (!mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName)) {
        echo "<p>Unable to connect to the $DBName database!</p>";
    } else {
        $SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM $TableName";
        $sql = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);
        $Message = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
        if ($Message === FALSE) {
            echo "Unable to execute the query." . "Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect) . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect) . "";
        } else if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
            echo "<h1>School of Healthcare and Wellbeing</h1>";
        } else {
            echo "<h1>" . $Message['message'] . "</h1>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the ST-words coming from $Message['message']? Have you tried to var_dump this variable?

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Comment: Check if the values are correctly stored in the db. If the values are already like that, then it's an expected output...

Comment: They are correctly in the database, and yes i've tried var_dump: this is the output:
string(62) "Test, mest, gerst, pest, string, stro, stippen, stip en stronk"

Comment: Inspect the page just to make sure. That's so weird...

Comment: Just inspected the page, there are the same values: <h1>Test, mest, gerst, pest, string, stro, stippen, stip en stronk</h1>

Comment: Had a similar problem with B2 as first two letters in a mysql table. Decided to not use this combination. But indeed very weird if it is 'st'. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the thing.. i switched my font to standard Arial and it works perfectly. Apparently there is some kind of bug with the font 'Radley'. I even tried several other fonts like Times and Courier. These fonts work fine! 
Anyway, it is fixed now!

Comment: I'm glad my comment helped ;)